# Swift Combine Conditional FlatMap Results

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, combine, flatmap

How can you have different return types for a flatMap when using Swift Combine? I have my first publisher, which emits a value and then I flatMap that to transform it into a new publisher. However, based on the original value, I might need to have a different publisher that returns a different type.

I've added a basic example below.

```
import Combine


class Testing{
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    
    func getTestScore()->AnyPublisher<Int, Never>{
        return Just(80).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func congratulate()->AnyPublisher<String, Never>{
        return Just("Good Job!").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getGPA()->AnyPublisher<Double, Never>{
        return Just(2.2).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init() {
        getTestScore()
            .flatMap{ score in
                if score < 70{
                    return self.getGPA()
                } else{
                    return self.congratulate()
                }
            }
            .sink { _ in } receiveValue: { value in
                print(value)
            }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

let testing = Testing()
```

Comment: `getGPA` emits `Double` values, and `congratulate` emits `String` values.. What is `.sink`  supposed to expect? It's similar to wanting to return a `Double` or a `String` from a function.. You can return an `Any`, of course, but that is just a poor design choice. You can consider an enum with associated values, possibly.

Comment: You're right that any is not a good solution. An enum with associated values probably isn't the best choice either.

Comment: In your question you posted a "toy" example... maybe the real issue isn't apparent in that example?

Comment: It's pretty much the same. The real issue is that I have a profile view where I load the user in. I then have to check if the user is the current logged in user. If it is, then I have to make two network calls (a & b). If its not the logged in user, then I only have to make network call a.

Comment: That sounds sufficiently different. I suggest you post a different question closer related to what you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As New Dev said, returning conditional data types is not possible - unless you don't want to erase the type to `Any`.

My proposal is to create one dedicated publisher which emits if the score exceeds (or falls below) a certain limit. Now use your new publisher to create two separate, type safe, pipelines. I'm aware that you asked to use just one pipeline. However, I think this approach will give you more benefits.

Please find my working example below:

```swift
import Combine

class Testing{
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func getTestScore()->AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        return Just(80).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func congratulate()->AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        return Just("Good Job!").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getGPA()->AnyPublisher<Double, Never> {
        return Just(2.2).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init() {
        let scoreExceedsLimit: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = getTestScore()
            .map { $0 >= 70 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        scoreExceedsLimit
            .filter { $0 == true }
            .flatMap { _ in self.congratulate() }
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                print("first pipeline: \(value)")
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        
        scoreExceedsLimit
            .filter { $0 == false }
            .flatMap { _ in self.getGPA() }
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                print("second pipeline: \(value)")
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

let testing = Testing()
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works fine, I just want to share an alternate way to solve it. Simply use an `enum` with an **associated value** to handle the different data types.

```
import Combine

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

class Testing{
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    enum ScoreResult {
        case success(String)
        case failure(Double)
    }
    
    func getTestScore()->AnyPublisher<Int, Never>{
        return [50, 80].publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func congratulate()->AnyPublisher<ScoreResult, Never>{
        return Just(.success("Good Job!")).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getGPA()->AnyPublisher<ScoreResult, Never>{
        return Just(.failure(2.2)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init() {
        getTestScore()
            .flatMap{ (score) -> AnyPublisher<ScoreResult, Never> in
                if score < 70 {
                    return self.getGPA()
                } else{
                    return self.congratulate()
                }
            }
            .sink { _ in } receiveValue: { value in
                print(value)
            }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

let testing = Testing()
```

This will print:

```
failure(2.2)
success("Good Job!")
```